# Getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" even though I'm not using a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running the following MySQL `UPDATE` statement:

```
mysql> update customer set account_import_id = 1;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I'm not using a transaction, so why would I be getting this error? I even tried restarting my MySQL server and it didn't help.

The table has 406,733 rows.

Comment: so far - no answers for how to increase the timeout. this may be the only solution in some cases.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You are using a transaction; autocommit does not disable transactions, it just makes them automatically commit at the end of the statement.

What could be happening is, some other thread is holding a record lock on some record (you're updating every record in the table!) for too long, and your thread is being timed out. Or maybe running multiple (2+) UPDATE queries on the same row during a single transaction.

You can see more details of the event by issuing a

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

after the event (in SQL editor). Ideally do this on a quiet test-machine.

Comment: Is there a way to save the output to a file? I tried SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G > innodb_stat.txt but doesn't work.

Comment: From command line: mysql [insert credentials] -e "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G" > innodb_stat.txt

Comment: if many mysql thread(or process) are busy, e.g. some query need very long time, so you have to wait some `process` to be idle. If so you could get this error. Am I right?

Comment: Running multiple (2+) UPDATE queries on the same row during a single transaction will also cause this error.

Comment: For those using Python MySQL Connector use `connection.commit()` to commit the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` you've just shot through.

Answer (score 518):

**HOW TO FORCE UNLOCK for locked tables in MySQL:**

Breaking locks like this may cause [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) in the database to not be enforced on the sql statements that caused the lock.

This is hackish, and the proper solution is to fix your application that caused the locks. However, when dollars are on the line, a swift kick will get things moving again.

1) Enter MySQL

```
mysql -u your_user -p
```

2) Let's see the list of locked tables

```
mysql> show open tables where in_use>0;
```

3) Let's see the list of the current processes, one of them is locking your table(s)

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

4) Kill one of these processes

```
mysql> kill <put_process_id_here>;
```

Comment: This method helps me to break the lock without PROCESS privilege.

Comment: This is dangerous and hackish.  A proper solution is to fix your application.

Comment: Nonsense, this lets you undo a messup and then fix the application. If I could give this guy 100 up votes for this issue which I had to fix NOW I would.

Comment: I agree with Lizardx.  This was a very useful solution in the situation that I didn't have the privilege to call SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

Comment: I was using Google cloud SQL and I had a job which was running for a long time. Following the steps mentioned helped we debug by error by checking the processes using my table in SQL.

Comment: `show processlist;` helped me more than `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. This is definitely a good rescue tip. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` may be useful for deeper debugging while trying to fix the root problem. All tools will have their own use.

Comment: How is killing a long-running query this way _dangerous_? The client calling will just get an error.

Comment: guys just don't forget to index relevant columns, a lot of times this is what causes the lock

Comment: Also this queries works not only from terminal. For example I have used Intellij to run it.

Comment: And what does it mean if we get OP's error and yet `show open tables where in_use>0;` results in `Empty set (0.00 sec)` ... something is very rotten in our database methinks

Comment: after the kill, the process remained there on state "KILLED"... so i restarted mysql ( i could do this in my case .. )

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I don't have the privileges to do `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, but I could kill the process in the database I was using and fix the issue

Comment: How is this answer relevant? The question is asking for an explanation of why OP's query is timing out on a transaction lock when they aren't using transactions. It isn't asking how to kill a long running query. Downvoted.

Answer (score 157):

```
mysql> set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 100   |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Now trigger the lock again. You have 100 seconds time to issue a `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` to the database and see which other transaction is locking yours.

Comment: This answer does not explain why the asker is getting their error. Could you elaborate on why besides just giving the answer?

Comment: +1 although this does not answers the question directly, for me it's a good reference to workaround this issue.

Comment: @ArtB https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout In essence the OP is receiving the error because a lock was called on the table and the time elapsed before ending the transaction exceeded the `lock_wait_timeout` value

Answer (score 106):

Take a look to see if your database is fine tuned, especially the transaction isolation. It isn't a good idea to increase the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable.

Check your database transaction isolation level in MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation, @@transaction_isolation, @@session.transaction_isolation;
+--------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation | @@transaction_isolation | @@session.transaction_isolation |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ                | REPEATABLE-READ         | REPEATABLE-READ                 |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could get improvements changing the isolation level. Use the Oracle-like `READ COMMITTED` instead of `REPEATABLE READ`. `REPEATABLE READ` is the InnoDB default.

```
mysql> SET transaction_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL transaction_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Also, try to use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` only  if necessary.

Comment: This is a great solution for locking issues.

Comment: Works great for me, the my.cnf version is 

[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED

Comment: Just a note: MySQL 8 has renamed `tx_isolation` variable to `transaction_isolation`.

Comment: Cares got to be taken to know what you're getting into when you change from read-isolation to READ COMMITTED though. You may end up with dirty data which you may want to avoid. [Wikipedia Isoloation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems))

Comment: This worked for me. Using python, SQL Alchemy was giving me a warning, which I always ignored, but on reading it, just maybe it was related:  Warning: '@@tx_isolation' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '@@transaction_isolation' instead
  cursor.execute('SELECT @@tx_isolation') - the isolation was set to READ-REPEATABLE, but after setting it to READ-COMMITTED, the locking issue was resolved. The process I had running was using about 8 threads writing to the db.

Comment: “The possibility of deadlocks is not affected by the isolation level, because the isolation level changes the behavior of read operations, while deadlocks occur because of write operations“ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Answer (score 50):

Something is blocking the execution of the query. Most likely another query updating, inserting or deleting from one of the tables in your query. You have to find out what that is:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Once you locate the blocking process, find its `id` and run :

```
KILL {id};
```

Re-run your initial query.

Comment: I accidently KILLED all processes listed with SHOW PROCESSLIST; Now I am getting 500 error in phpmyadmin. Is that 500 error related to killing these processes ? If yes, how can I restart it.

Comment: I can see what you describe, however killing the process doesn't work. The process' command is "killed", but it remains in the process list.

Answer (score 19):

```
mysql->SHOW PROCESSLIST;
kill xxxx;
```

and then kill which one in sleep. In my case it is 2156.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

100% with what MarkR said. autocommit makes each statement a one statement transaction.

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` should give you some clues as to the deadlock reason. Have a good look at your slow query log too to see what else is querying the table and try to remove anything that's doing a full tablescan. Row level locking works well but not when you're trying to lock all of the rows!

Answer (score 6):

Try to update the below two parameters as they must be having default values.

> innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

> innodb_rollback_on_timeout = ON

For checking parameter value you can use the below SQL.

> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_rollback_on_timeout';

Comment: This answer does not explain why this is the solution and what is the meaning of the change. Could you elaborate on why besides just giving the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Can you update any other record within this table,  or is this table heavily used?  What I am thinking is that while it is attempting to acquire a lock that it needs to update this record the timeout that was set has timed out.  You may be able to increase the time which may help.

Comment: maybe `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` in `my.cnf`

Comment: I set in my.cnf:<br/>innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120<br/>The default is 50 for mysql 5.5. After this change I was not able to see this issue in my unit tests! This happened after switching from proxool to tomcat jdbc pool. Probably due to more transaction time with tomcat pool?!

Answer (score 5):

In our case the problem did not have much to do with the locks themselves.

The issue was that one of our application endpoints needed to open 2 connections in parallel to process a single request.

**Example:**

1. Open 1st connection
2. Start transaction 1
3. Lock 1 row in table1
4. Open 2nd connection
5. Start transaction 2
6. Lock 1 row in table2
7. Commit transaction 2
8. Release 2nd connection
9. Commit transaction 1
10. Release 1st connection

Our application had a connection pool limited to 10 connections.

Unfortunately, under load, as soon as all connections were used the application stopped working and we started having this problem.
We had several requests that needed to open a second connection to complete, but could not due to the connection pool limit. As a consequence, those requests were keeping a lock on the table1 row for a long time leading the following requests that needed to lock the same row to throw this error.

**Solution:**

- *In the short term*, we patched the problem by increasing the connection pool limit.
- *In the long term*, we removed all nested connections, to fully solve the issue.

**Tips:**

You can easily check if you have nested connections by trying to lower your connection pool limit to 1 and test your application.

Answer (score 4):

If you've just killed a big query, it will take time to `rollback`. If you issue another query before the killed query is done rolling back, you might get a lock timeout error. That's what happened to me. The solution was just to wait a bit.

Details:

I had issued a DELETE query to remove about 900,000 out of about 1 million rows.

I ran this by mistake (removes only 10% of the rows):
`DELETE FROM table WHERE MOD(id,10) = 0`

Instead of this (removes 90% of the rows):
`DELETE FROM table WHERE MOD(id,10) != 0`

I wanted to remove 90% of the rows, not 10%. So I killed the process in the MySQL command line, knowing that it would roll back all the rows it had deleted so far.

Then I ran the correct command immediately, and got a `lock timeout exceeded` error soon after. I realized that the lock might actually be the `rollback` of the killed query still happening in the background. So I waited a few seconds and re-ran the query.

Comment: I just had the same thing when the server rebooted during a large update.

Answer (score 2):

The number of rows is not huge... Create an index on account_import_id if its not the primary key.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer_account_import_id ON customer (account_import_id);
```

Comment: OMG...this just saved me. I royally screwed a production DB by dropping an index and this fixed it. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the database tables are using InnoDB storage engine and READ-COMMITTED transaction isolation level.

You can check it by `SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;` on mysql console.

If it is not set to be READ-COMMITTED then you must set it. Make sure before setting it that you have SUPER privileges in mysql.

You can take help from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html.

By setting this I think your problem will be get solved.

---

You might also want to check you aren't attempting to update this in two processes at once. Users ( @tala ) have encountered similar error messages in this context, maybe double-check that...

Answer (score 1):

I came from Google and I just wanted to add the solution that worked for me. My problem was I was trying to delete records of a huge table that had a lot of FK in cascade so I got the same error as the OP.

I disabled the `autocommit` and then it worked just adding `COMMIT` at the end of the SQL sentence. As far as I understood this releases the buffer bit by bit instead of waiting at the end of the command.

To keep with the example of the OP, this should have worked:

`mysql> set autocommit=0;`

`mysql> update customer set account_import_id = 1; commit;`

Do not forget to reactivate the `autocommit` again if you want to leave the MySQL config as before.

`mysql> set autocommit=1;`

Answer (score 1):

This is an edge case, but this exact error can occur of the volume the database reside on runs out of space.  I found this page searching for the solution but nothing was working, I then noticed that other things on the server were acting strangely.  A df -h showed 100% in use.  I shut the instance down, increased the size of the volume and restarted the instance and the problem resolved itself.  This is AWS EC2.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Simply restart the mysql server

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party (as usual) however my issue was the fact that I wrote some bad SQL (being a novice) and several processes had a lock on the record(s) <-- not sure the appropriate verbiage. I ended up having to just: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and then kill the IDs using `KILL <id>`

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing happened to me when I was using php
language construct exit; in middle of transaction. Then this
transaction "hangs" and you need to kill mysql process (described above with processlist;)

Answer (score 0):

In my instance, I was running an abnormal query to fix data.  **If you lock the tables in your query, then you won't have to deal with the Lock timeout:**

```
LOCK TABLES `customer` WRITE;
update customer set account_import_id = 1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This is probably not a good idea for normal use.

For more info see:  [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this having 2 Doctrine DBAL connections, one of those as non-transactional (for important logs), they are intended to run parallel not depending on each other.

```
CodeExecution(
    TransactionConnectionQuery()
    TransactionlessConnectionQuery()
)
```

My integration tests were wrapped into transactions for data rollback after very test.

```
beginTransaction()
CodeExecution(
    TransactionConnectionQuery()
    TransactionlessConnectionQuery() // CONFLICT
)
rollBack()
```

My solution was to disable the wrapping transaction in those tests and reset the db data in another way.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue yesterday and after slogging through just about every suggested solution here, and several others from other answers/forums we ended up resolving it once we realized the actual issue.

Due to some poor planning, our database was stored on a mounted volume that was also receiving our regular automated backups. That volume had reached max capacity.

Once we cleared up some space and restarted, this error was resolved.

Note that we did also manually kill several of the processes: `kill <process_id>;` so that may still be necessary.

Overall, our takeaway was that it was incredibly frustrating that none of our logs or warnings directly mentioned a lack of disk space, but that did seem to be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when using python to access mysql database.
The python program was using a while and for loop.
Closing cursor and link at appropriate line solved problem
https://github.com/nishishailesh/sensa_host_com/blob/master/sensa_write.py
see line 230
It appears that asking repeated link without closing previous link produced this error

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue when doing some testing.

**Reason** - In my case transaction was not committed from my spring boot application because I killed the @transactional function during the execution(when the function was updating some rows). Due to which transaction was never committed to the database(MySQL).

**Result** - not able to update those rows from anywhere. But able to update other rows of the table.

```
mysql> update some_table set some_value = "Hello World" where id = 1;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

**Solution** - killed all the MySQL processes using

- **sudo killall -9 mysqld**

[image]

- sudo killall -9 mysqld_safe (restarting the server when an error occurs and logging runtime information to an error log. Not required in my case)

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was failing to commit after an update or delete.

```sql
show processlist
```

showed a long list of sleeping connections.

Answer (score 0):

Well in mysql 8 we can do following to prevent lock timeouts

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM customer FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
UPDATE customer SET account_import_id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

**FOR UPDATE** keyword will lock the selected rows, **SKIP LOCKED** on other hand will skip already locked rows. If we have this executed simultaneously no lock wait timeouts will happen and the first one will do the job without blocking the other.

This approach is perfect to avoid lock timeouts and needs to be applied carefully and understand how it works.

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html#:~:text=A%20locking%20read%20that%20uses,rows%20from%20the%20result%20set.&text=Queries%20that%20skip%20locked%20rows,suitable%20for%20general%20transactional%20work](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html#:%7E:text=A%20locking%20read%20that%20uses,rows%20from%20the%20result%20set.&text=Queries%20that%20skip%20locked%20rows,suitable%20for%20general%20transactional%20work).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem temporarily by setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size=64MB` on `my.cnf` file.

It's not recommended, but it's much needed when in need of a quick solution.

Comment: How is that not recommended ? I thought it helps to set that at higher values for large databases. I use 90G buffer pool size now for a 70GB database.

Answer (score 0):

```
show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';

SET global innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1200;
```

Answer (score -1):

Running this command worked for me

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Someone might run it on production env. Please put a disclaimer

Answer (score -4):

Had this same error, even though I was only updating one table with one entry, but after restarting mysql, it was resolved.