# Why can't I edit a mysql database remotely?

Tags: mysql

So I recently formatted, and reset up my lamp server on Ubuntu 12.04. I have everything right, accept I can't seem to edit anything on mysql from a remote account, though I can view it. I know I have the remote access set up correctly (as I can view my databases fine) but I can't edit anything. I thought it was a user privilege error at first but after trying to log in I viewed my privileges and confirmed that:

```
mysql> show grants for 'tom'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'tom'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'BLAHBLAHMYENCRIPTED PASSWORDISN'TIMPORTANT' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I can not figure out what is wrong. I have searched, and searched, and no one else seems to have this problem.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to edit something?

Comment: I'm editing it via a java program I wrote (that worked fine before the reformat on the exact same database) and it gives me a communication link error when I try to edit something (insert,delete, and update only) but as long as I am only using the select command, it works fine.

Comment: Does it give some more enlightening details than that? You should be getting an error from mySQL....

Comment: ahh, yes, sorry it tells me:  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Hmm, I think that won't help to get clarity about what happens... It would probably be good if you could use a proper mySQL client so you can get the real message from the server

Comment: alright, give me a few minutes to get that info to you.

Comment: from SQL Workbench: 0 18:58:20 UPDATE User_Data SET Value='7' WHERE User_Name = 'tom' Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: In the same instance(no error):  3 19:05:25 select * from User_Data LIMIT 0, 1000 2 row(s) returned

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem related to privileges. See eg. [Getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" even though I'm not using a transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5836623)