# Why Python/Django does not raise exception on Mysql: ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: python, mysql, django, exception, locking

I am testing locking in my MySQL db from python/django.

I have a table, I am testing on:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into test (id) values (1), (2);
commit;
```

I have 3 sessions:
 - 2 mysql console
 - 1 django view

Console 1:

```
mysql> begin; select t.id from test as where id = 1 t FOR UPDATE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Console 2:

```
mysql> set @@session.innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select t.id from test as t FOR UPDATE;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

mysql> select t.id from test as t where id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Django view:

```
@db.transaction.commit_manually
def Test(request):
  c = db.connection.cursor()
  c.execute('set @@session.innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1')
  c.execute('select t.id from test as t FOR UPDATE')
  logging.error(c.fetchall())
  c.execute('select t.id from test as t where id = 1 FOR UPDATE')
  logging.error(c.fetchall())
  db.transaction.rollback()

  return render_to_response(
      'test.html',
      context_instance=template.RequestContext(request, {})
      )
```

After calling this view I would expect an exception, but nothing happens, it returns an empty result set.

Any ideas why?

Versions:

- Python: 2.7.3
- Django: 1.4.3
- MySQL: 5.5

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Do you get other errors like foreign key errors?

Comment: Yes, I get such exceptions.
And the funny part is that if I run 'select t.id from test as t FOR UPDATE' there is no exception, but if I only run 'select t.id from test as t where id = 1 FOR UPDATE' then I get DatabaseError. So now I am totally confused :)

Answer (score 0):

> You are using a transaction; autocommit does not disable transactions, it just makes them automatically commit at the end of the statement.
>
> What is happening is, some other thread is holding a record lock on some record for too long, and your thread is being timed out.
>
> *Source:* [Getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" even though I'm not using a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im)

You should increase the lock wait timeout value for InnoDB by setting the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50` (default) or set it to higher value and restart MySQL.