# Database choking on query from django (mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am doing some image processing, specifically making thumbnails.  After thumbnails are complete, I update a field in my database image table:

```
Image.objects.filter(file_name__in=images).update(thumbnailed=True)
```

The table has gotten to be a medium size (about 2 million records) and I started getting the following error:

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

In looking for a solution, I came across this thread:

[Getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" even though I'm not using a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im)

It has some good ideas including increasing the timeout config setting.

Is there a way to more efficiently run this update from Django that would not require changes to the database configuration?

Comment: How large is images? Because IN statements can take quite a while to evaluate. Is there an index on file_name? Also if possible it's better to do a check on the id, since id checks are generally cheaper then varchar comparisons.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the point regarding the ids.  The images table is around 2 million records. I am going to switch the query to use the id field and see if that helps.

Comment: How large is the images list which you pass to file_name__in was what I meant.

Comment: Is your db in the same box as the Django process? If `images` list is very large, it might be taking a while just to transfer the SQL query to the db server. Either way, using ids should make things faster.

Comment: So the images list was 200 images.  I reduced the list size to 50 and the problem subsided for now

Comment: Note that `IN` (the SQL clause) also has a limit so keeping your queries in check is a good idea in general.