# Innodb_lock_wait_timeout issue for magento

Tags: mysql, magento, innodb

I am facing error in Innodb_lock_wait_timeout issue on MySQL. My application is on Magento and databases size is around 84 GB. While running Individual commands for re-indexing I am getting following error.
`MySQL Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction.`

NOTE:- Mysql server is having 16 GB ram separately.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Comment: Is the issue related to uploading a large size DB ?