# Cancelling thread task

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, multithreading

I've got a MySQL connection which is executing a query in a separate thread, represented by a Task.

Through the cancellation token, I am stopping this thread when the user clicks a button.

My problem is that an error is being presented saying the following: `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

This is my code:

```
cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

 await Task.Run(() =>
     {
       using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(sourceDatabaseConnectionString))
            {
               connection.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
                        {
                            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", datePicker.Value.Month);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", datePicker.Value.Year);
                            int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
            }
     }, cancellationToken.Token);
```

On button press, I'm calling `cancellationToken.Cancel();`

When I try to execute the SQL statement again by starting the task, I get the error message shown above.  What could be causing it?

Comment: I bet the most intresting part is under "//Execute query" comment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Comment: @vtortola - That question does not seem to explain how to solve it though, other than manually killing the process within MySQL. When cancelling the thread/Task, the query should be cancelled too, no?

Comment: I think the problem maybe in the SQL you are using here and in other queries and not directly related to your C# code. Probably when you call "Cancel", a exception is thrown in that code, that you should catch to "Rollback" the transaction, otherwise locks still exists when you try to run again.

Comment: Why will the task be cancelled? Nothing is there to actually observe the cancellation. Don't you want `ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken.Token)`? Do you just presume it to be cancelled? I doubt that the TPL will `Thread.Abort` a `Task` to cancel it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Through the cancellation token, I am stopping this thread when the user clicks a button.

Passing a cancellation token to `Run(Action, CancellationToken)` doesn't magically make the `Task` (once executing) cancelable. Look at the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) which uses `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

If it was possible to say *okay arbitrary `Task` executing arbitrary code, please cancel yourself* then there'd be no need for cancellation tokens because you could simply do `Task.Cancel()`.

You probably intend to use [`OpenAsync(CancellationToken)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223693(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223683(v=vs.110).aspx).

You end up with a lock timeout because you're waiting on your "cancelled" non-cancelled task.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx

Briefly, it is written there how to allow program to continue upon a cancellation request even if the operation being waited on hasn’t completed yet. This should be also useful for handling such an error.