# AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Tags: python, mysql

```
def fillblast(sequentie, titel_lijst, score_lijst, e_lijst, iden_lijst, pos_lijst, gaps_lijst): 
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "ithurtswhenip.nl", user = "pg2", password = "pg2", database= "pg2", port= "3307") 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    Blast = 1000
    for i in range(0,len(titel_lijst)):
        Blast =+ 2
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `pg2`.`Blast` (`Blast_id`, `Blast_seq`, `Blast_titel`, `Blast_score`, `Blast_E`, `Blast_gaps`, `Blast_pos`, `Blast_iden`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", (Blast, sequentie[i] ,titel_lijst[i], score_lijst[i], e_lijst[i], iden_lijst[i], pos_lijst[i], gaps_lijst[i]))
        print("1 record toegevoegd")
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close() 
    conn.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'commit'
```

How does it come, and where does it go wrong?
I try to connect with MySQLWorkbench.

*EDIT:*

Now I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Comment: Oh, I have use conn.close() not cursor.close()

Comment: You can always edit your post

Comment: You must use `conn.commit()` not `cursor.commit()`

Comment: Now I get the following error: "mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im) for info about database timeout. Probably your `titel_lijst` is too long and inserting too many rows which consumes a lot of time, more than the MySql transaction timeout limit, so your connection time-out.

Answer (score 61):

Because you can not commit a cursor! you must commit the connection.

```
# cursor.commit() --> This is wrong!
conn.commit()  # This is right
```

[Check the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html)...

Comment: I am using, connection.commit() but getting same error

Answer (score 1):

While fixing some legacy code (that apparently hasn't been working for a couple of years, so users stopped trying to use it), we ran into the same error, using the MySQL-python package in Django. Using the suggestions on this and other answers however resulted in a different error, on account of it occurring within the Django ORM:

> django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: This code isn't
>   under transaction management

So for those who run into this error after using conn.commit() instead of cursor.commit(), you may be able to use `enter_transaction_management` and `leave_transaction_management` (note that this was for Django 1.4.6 and MySQL-python 1.2.5; I may have to update this once we get the Django upgrade completed):

```
    try:
        conn.enter_transaction_management()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        cursor.rollback()
        log.warning('log warning here')
    # Handle other exceptions here.
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        conn.leave_transaction_management()
```