# Python3 - 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' and only process on the database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Using Python I am consistently getting an

```
(1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

error whenever I try to insert into a particular table. However, when I try to insert directly from the MySQL console, it works just fine. Looking into the

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

on the database reveals no other active queries. As this is a dev database with no live applications attached I can't envision any problem. However, it is being served on a server which hosts our production databases, so I strongly prefer not to do resets if possible. Any advice on how to debug this?

**Note**
If I view the query being run against the database using *SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST*, that eventually fails with the above message, and then insert it manually from the MySQL console, it works as expected.

**EDIT**
Here is an example of the query:

```
INSERT INTO deals (user_ID, store_ID, storeChain_ID, title, dealSaving, 
dealDisclaimer, restriction, dealImage, dealURL, submit_ID, userProvider_ID, 
createDate, createDateTime, expirationDate, expirationDateTime, ZIP, STATE, 
city, businessType, DealType_ID, IP, rating, popular, dealSearchData, tag, 
submitName, provider_dealID)
VALUES (NULL,
        2651049,
        NULL,
        'Toronto East Community Arts Program',
        'Three-Week Photography Workshop',
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'https://a1.image.net/imgs/8423535b-bd3b-4e1e-afee-ab2869970a4c/700_q60.jpg',
        'https://www.exmples.com/deals/1336374',
        111,
        1,
        '2015-11-12',
        '2015-11-12 10:01:58.282826',
        '2015-11-17 09:59:59',
        '2015-11-17 23:59:00',
        'M4M 1K7',
        'ON',
        'Toronto',
        NULL,
        '1',
        '127.0.0.1',
        0,
        144565,
        'Three-Week Photography Workshop',
        'Photography Class',
        'Partner',
        1336374)
```

**Edit**
An example using the suggestion is as follows:

```
self.DB['master']['cursor'].execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED")
self.DB['master']['con'].commit()
self.DB['master']['cursor'].execute(dealsquery,data)
self.DB['master']['con'].commit()
```

Comment: can you show your python query?

Comment: I added an example query

Comment: Do you work with multiple threads.?

Comment: Nope, it's single threaded.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out, a different component was making a connection and missing the commit() statement.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe MySql uses "Repeatable Read" isolation, which will hold a lock, for the ENTIRE transaction (aka until commit, i believe). try using a different isolation setting like "Read Committed"

To set read commited in python mysql is something like

`cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")`

edit: a good introductory resource for isolation levels
http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/

Comment: I tried adding this before my actual insert statement, but the problem still persists.

Comment: did you commit the change before inserting? Also, are you commiting your insert before continuing?

Comment: Yea, every insert is followed by a commit and I also tried committing the statement before my insert. I added an example to my original question

Comment: take a gander over here, maybe it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Comment: I noticed an error in my code, Try using commited instead of uncommited