# How to efficiently calculate averages from a big table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called *ratings* with the following fields:

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rating_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| movie_id  | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rating    | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Indexes on this table:

```
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| ratings |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | rating_id   | A         |      100076 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| ratings |          0 | user_id  |            1 | user_id     | A         |         564 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| ratings |          0 | user_id  |            2 | movie_id    | A         |      100092 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I have another table called `movie_average_ratings` which has the following fields:

```
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| movie_id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| average_rating | float   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

As it is obvious by this point I want to calculate the average rating of movies from **ratings** table and update the `movie_average_ratings`table. I tried the following SQL query.

```
UPDATE movie_average_ratings
SET average_rating = (SELECT AVG(rating)
                            FROM ratings
                            WHERE ratings.movie_id = movie_average_ratings.movie_id);
```

Currently, there are around 10,000 movie records and 100,000 rating records and I get `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` error. The number of records can grow significantly so I don't think increase timeout is a good solution.

So, how can I write 'scalable' query to acheive this? Is iterating the `movie_average_ratings` table records and calculate averages individually the most efficient solution to this?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd bother storing derived data. Are you having performance issues?

Comment: Please show a schema (with indexes), and an explain. 10000 records is almost nothing for a well-indexed database.

Comment: @Strawberry I hope to achieve some slight performance gain by storing averages.

Comment: @NevilleK I updated the question. On `ratings` table, there is a compound UNIQUE key on `user_id` and `movie_id`.

Comment: @NevilleK I have 10,000 movie records but 100,000 rating records which will grow significantly.

Comment: please show the explain - and the indexes for all tables. Also, what happens when you execute Select movie_ID, avg(rating) from table group by movie_id?

Comment: @NevilleK That query executes fine. Takes around 0.04 seconds.

Comment: @NevilleK I have updated the question with the table schema and indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an `explain`, it's hard to be clear on what's holding you up. It's also not clear that you will get a performance improvement by storing this aggregated data as a denormalized table - if the query to calculate the ratings executes in 0.04 seconds, it's unlikely querying your denormalized table will be much faster.

In general, I recommend only denormalizing if you *know* you have a performance problem.

But that's not the question.

I would do the following:

```
delete from movie_average_ratings;

insert into movie_average_ratings
Select movie_ID, avg(rating) 
from ratings 
group by movie_id;
```

Comment: I did include `explain` in the question.

Comment: I can't see it - did you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html?

Comment: Are you sure? I have updated this question to include the console output of `explain`. Hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im):

> What is happening is, some other thread is holding a record lock on
>   some record (you're updating every record in the table!) for too long,
>   and your thread is being timed out.

This means that some of your records are locked you can force unlock them in the console:

> 1) Enter MySQL `mysql -u your_user -p`
>
> 2) Let's see the list of locked tables `mysql> show open tables where in_use>0;`
>
> 3) Let's see the list of the current processes, one of them is locking
>   your table(s) `mysql> show processlist;`
>
> 4) Kill one of these processes `mysql> kill put_process_id_here;`

Comment: I know the table is put on lock as long as the update operation is running. My question is what would be a better way to update the table? If the table has records in order of 100,000 or a million, it will take way too long.

Answer (score 0):

You could redesign the movie_average_ratings table to

```
movie_id (int)
sum_of_ratings (int)
num_of_ratings (int)
```

Then, if a new rating is added you can add it to movie_average_ratings and calculate the average if needed

Comment: To calculate the sum I will have to again use `SUM` function. Brings us to square one. After setting up average table I do plan to use "moving average" method to update ratings. But the problem is initial setup of the table.

Comment: You don't store individual ratings in movie_average_ratings table!

If you get a new rating just add it to sum_of_ratings and increment num_of_ratings