# Talend - how to solve - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: talend

I am using talend ETL open source . I have pull the data from MSSQL to MysQL its around 8000 records . Previously its was working fine . Now I got below kind of issue .
**Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**
Could you please provide the solution for how to rectify this issue.
error:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3349
[statistics] connected
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
100574 milliseconds
[statistics] disconnected
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your job ?

Comment: I have posted my job .Kindly look.

Comment: I'm guessing your source table is being locked by another query. Could you please try adding "WITH (NOLOCK)" after your table(s) in the source query?

Comment: Ok i will check and come back to you .

Comment: I got same issue . Any other work around solution?

Comment: I was mistaken, it seems to be a MySQL issue. Please look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5836623/899863

Comment: Yes I got solution . I have changed the DB settings in Mysql . Now working fine. Thanks for you support.

Comment: Great ! Could you please add an answer and mark it as accepted ? It would help people who have the same problem as you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168386/discussion-between-antony-and-imezouar).

Comment: set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
SET tx_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';
SET GLOBAL tx_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';