# Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction MYSQL Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have Flask app which makes SQL updates:

```
 query = 'update tbl set x="bla" where filename=%s';
 cursor.execute(query, fileName)
```

This code worked well with multiple files. 
Suddenly i'm starting to get this errors while updating (Error rises up again in each update call).

```
InternalError: (1205, u'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

I've seen similar posts like 
[Getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" even though I'm not using a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im)

But it didn't solve my problem.

This is my process list: 
[image]

Tried to kill some sleeping processes but it didn't work.

Info from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`:

```
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 439228, OS thread handle 139653215057664, query id 7055088 10.66.85.134 admin updating
update tbl set vt_status=\"rescan\" where filename=\'3ec7il\'
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 131151, sees < 131145
```

Answer (score 2):

`Try/except` finally solved it

```
try:
   conn = getConn()
finally:
   conn.close()
```