# transaction when to delete data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a delete statement when running that getting error

```
#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

my delete statement is

```
DELETE FROM `hotspot_sentences` WHERE doc_id = 459
```

when i run

```
show open tables WHERE In_use > 0
```

getting 0 no of rows

on running `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

[image]

Comment: try `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`. This output should help you identify the cause for the lockup.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Fang i updated  the question please check

Comment: How many rows do you have in table, and what is the timeout set in mysql ? try with **SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_lock_wait_timeout%'**