# java- How to set rollback function on inserting records to table?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a program where I extract some records from a PDF file, then I proceed to insert those records into a table in MySQL.

One of my main concern is if there is an error under any circumstances during the inserting to table. Let's say if I am inserting 1000 records from a file into the table and halfway, something bad happens. So does it auto rollback or do I need to include a `"Begin Transaction and Commit Transaction"` statement?

If so, how do I initiate a rollback inside Java? I am thinking of writing a rollback function just to achieve this.

My code:

```
 public void index(String path) throws Exception {

     PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
     if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
         PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
         String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
         String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
         for (String line : lines) {
             String[] words = line.split(" ");
             String sql="insert IGNORE into test.indextable values (?,?)";
             // con.connect().setAutoCommit(false);
             preparedStatement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
             int i=0;
             for (String word : words) {
                 // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                 // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
                // insert every word directly to table db
                word=word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
                preparedStatement.setString(1, path);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, word);
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
                i++;
                if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                    System.out.print("Add Thousand");
                }  
            }
            if (i > 0) {
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                System.out.print("Add Remaining");
            }

        }

    }

    // con.connect().commit();
    preparedStatement.close();
    System.out.println("Successfully commited changes to the database!");
}
```

This function above will be called by another function to be executed and the try and catch exception is in the caller function.

My rollback function:

```
 // function to undo entries in inverted file on error indexing
 public void rollbackEntries() throws Exception {
     con.connect().rollback();
     System.out.println("Successfully rolled back changes from the database!");
 }
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It only rolls back if you tell it to roll back. I would suggest adding a try catch to anything which could happen in order to trigger a rollback when and where the incident occurs. Right now if something happens, the exception would just propagate and stop your program completely.

Comment: Am i doing it correctly? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what library you are using, so I am just going to guess on exception names and types. If you look in the api you can check to see what exceptions are thrown by what functions.

```
private final static String INSERT_STATMENT = "insert IGNORE into test.indextable values (?,?)";

public void index(String path) { // Don't throw the exception, handle it.
     PDDocument document = null;
     try {
         document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println("Unable to find document \"" + path "\"!");
         return;
     }

     if (document == null || document.isEncrypted()) {
             System.err.println("Unable to read data from document \"" + path "\"!");
             return;
     }

     String[] lines = null;

     try {
         PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper(); 
         lines = stripper.getText(document).split("\\r?\\n");
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Could not read data from document \"" + path "\"! File may be corrupted!");
         return;
     }

     // You can add in extra checks just to test for other specific edge cases
     if (lines == null || lines.length < 2) {
         System.err.println("Only found 1 line in document \"" + path "\"! File may be corrupted!");
         return;
     }


     for (String line : lines) {
         PreparedStatement statement = con.connect().prepareStatement(INSERT_STATMENT );
             String[] words = line.split(" ");

             for (int index = 0, executeWait = 0; index < words.length; index++, executeWait++) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, path);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, words[index].replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                preparedStatement.addBatch();

                // Repeat this part again like before
                if (executeWait % 1000 == 0) {
                    for (int timeout = 0; true; timeout++) {
                        try {
                            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                            System.out.print("Pushed " + (((executeWait - 1) % 1000) + 1) + " statements to database.");
                            break;
                        } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
                            if (timeout >= 5) {
                                System.err.println("Unable to resolve issues! Exiting...");
                                return;
                            }
                            System.err.println("Lost connection to database! Fix attempt " + (timeout + 1) + ". (Timeout at 5)");
                            con.reconnect();
                        } catch (SqlWriteException error) {
                            System.err.println("Error while writing to database. Rolling back changes and retrying. Fix attempt " + (timeout + 1) + ". (Timeout at 5)");
                            rollbackEntries();
                            if (timeout >= 5) {
                                System.err.println("Unable to resolve issues! Exiting...");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }

        }

    try {
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Do nothing since it means it was already closed. 
        // Probably throws an exception to prevent people from calling this method twice.
    }
    System.out.println("Successfully committed all changes to the database!");
}
```

There are definitely a few more exceptions which you will need to account for which I didn't add.

---

**Edit: Your specific issue can be found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im)**

Comment: Wow, you changed the complexion of my code. The problem is I have to set autocommit to false and when I do that and run my code, it throws SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded. try restarting transaction

Comment: Probably means that your batch size is too large. It probably times out if it is unable to complete a commit in a certain amount of time. Chances are there is also a `preparedStatement.executeBatch(int timeoutMillis)` if you want to keep your larger batch sizes though.

Comment: That'ts not true though because I tried removing by adding by batches and add them one by one and it stills throws this issue.