# Laravel job lock wait timeout, SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: laravel, timeout, locking, jobs

I got this below error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL: select * from jobs where queue = default and ((reserved_at is null and available_at <= 1694496529) or (reserved_at <= 1694496439)) order by id asc limit 1 for update)

Has anyone gone through the above issue in the job process, and how to fix this issue

Comment: Did you try to check this error in other stack overflow questions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63894765

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5836623