# Issue with Updating a value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image: branch_supplier table]

I want to change "Stamford Lables" under supplier_name to "Stamford Labels". I used the following.

```
UPDATE branch_supplier
SET supplier_name = "Stamford Labels"
WHERE supplier_name="Stamford Lables" and branch_id = 3;
```

This however does not work and the program just halts and does not do anything and just give timeout message a moment later.

I appreciate any help.

Other details:

`branch_id` and `supplier_name` are the primary keys.

Error Message:

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Update:
I found the issue. I was using mysql.connector in Python to access the server. I forgot to put db.commit() so my previous processes must be blocking it. I kill all the processes and now the update query works.

Comment: Is this on a live database or on a local dev one?

Most likely something has locked the rows and you can't update them.

Comment: The table is locked by another process? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: yeah. It is hosted on a server.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález How do I check that? I can access the processlist

Comment: @LinnHtetAung table is locked by some transaction. Run command SHOW PROCESS to check the process id and kill it.

Comment: Try `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im)

Comment: Try `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

Comment: Thanks everyone I managed to solve it.