# MySql CREATE TABLE statement fails with lock timeout yet no locks are shown

Tags: mysql

I'm executing a statement to create a table that selects from another table

`CREATE TABLE tmpTable SELECT a.* FROM otherTable a;`

This fails with

`Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Executing
`SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE In_use > 0;`
shows nothing, and `show processlist;` shows only sleeping processes.

I can execute the select statement on it's own fine
`SELECT a.* FROM otherTable a;`

Does anyone know why I cannot create the table?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Answer (score 1):

A session can hold a lock on `OtherTable` even if that session isn't running a query against it. Locks are held until the session commits its transaction. But it can be idle between queries. The locks are still held.

You can demonstrate this in a test.

In one window, start a transaction against a table.

```
mysql> create table OtherTable (id int primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into OtherTable values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update OtherTable set id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Don't commit this transaction yet.

In a second window, run SHOW PROCESSLIST. You see your session that is running that command, but the other session is only doing "Sleep." That is, it's not running a query at the current moment. It still has an uncommitted transaction, and it still has locks, but that is not shown by the processlist.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+------------------------+------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time   | State                  | Info             |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+------------------------+------------------+
| 41 | root            | localhost | test | Sleep   |      3 |                        | NULL             |
| 42 | root            | localhost | test | Query   |      0 | init                   | show processlist |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+------------------------+------------------+
```

In your second window, try the `CREATE TABLE...SELECT`.

```
mysql> create table tmpTable select a.* from OtherTable a;
...waits for 50 seconds...
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Why did SELECT require locks on OtherTable?

It required shared locks. This happens in many circumstances when a query that creates or modifies data reads from another table.

- `INSERT...SELECT`
- `SELECT ... INTO`
- `SET @variable = (SELECT...);`
- `UPDATE` a table that references a foreign key in a parent table (the parent table's rows get a shared lock)
- `SELECT` a table in a trigger

Any number of sessions can simultaneously hold shared locks. But any shared lock blocks an exclusive lock, and vice versa.

So you must have another session that had previously done some `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` operation on `OtherTable`, finished that operation, but then left its transaction uncommitted, so it still holds the exclusive locks it acquired.

Unfortunately, it's not easy in MySQL to figure out which session and which update is responsible.

In the future, design your client applications to COMMIT their transaction promptly after doing SQL statements that acquire locks.

Right now, all you can do is make a best guess and KILL one or more sessions that you think hold the locks.