# 'Lock wait timeout exceeded' when trying to implement outbox pattern with Spring Integration and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to implement the outbox pattern using Spring Integration. I configured the following beans:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringIntegrationTestApplicationConfiguration {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringIntegrationTestApplicationConfiguration.class);

    public static final String CONCURRENT_METADATA_STORE_PREFIX = "_spring_integration_";

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface EmailGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "mailbox")
        void sendEmail(String mailBody,
                       @Header String target);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcChannelMessageStore messageStore(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore = new JdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource);
        jdbcChannelMessageStore.setTablePrefix(CONCURRENT_METADATA_STORE_PREFIX);
        jdbcChannelMessageStore.setChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider(
                new MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider());
        return jdbcChannelMessageStore;
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentMetadataStore concurrentMetadataStore(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcMetadataStore jdbcMetadataStore = new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
        jdbcMetadataStore.setTablePrefix(CONCURRENT_METADATA_STORE_PREFIX);
        return jdbcMetadataStore;
    }


    @Bean
    MessageHandler sendEmailMessageHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                String target = (String) message.getHeaders().get("target");
                LOGGER.info("not sending email with body: {} {}", message, target);
                throw new RuntimeException("");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    QueueChannel mailboxChannel(JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore) {
        return MessageChannels.queue(jdbcChannelMessageStore, "mailbox").getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow buildFlow(ChannelMessageStore channelMessageStore,
                                     MessageHandler sendEmailMessageHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("mailbox")
                              .routeToRecipients(routes -> {
                                  routes
                                          .transactional()
                                          .recipientFlow(flow -> flow
                                                  .channel(channels -> channels.queue(channelMessageStore, "outbox"))
                                                  .handle(sendEmailMessageHandler, e -> e.poller(poller -> poller.fixedDelay(1000).transactional()))
                                          );
                              }).get();
    }

}
```

I also have an ApplicationRunner to test drive the thing:

```
@Component
public class Runner implements ApplicationRunner {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class);

    private final SpringIntegrationTestApplicationConfiguration.EmailGateway emailGateway;

    public Runner(SpringIntegrationTestApplicationConfiguration.EmailGateway emailGateway) {
        this.emailGateway = emailGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Sending 1");
        emailGateway.sendEmail("This is my body", "target");
        LOGGER.info("Sending 2");
        emailGateway.sendEmail("This is my body2", "target2");
    }
}
```

I have setup MySQL with `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8-oracle
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'sidb'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      timeout: 10s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10
```

And configured via `application.properties` to use that database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sidb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

The necessairy tables have been configured via Flyway (See https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/spring-integration-test/blob/main/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__init.sql).

The full sources can be viewed at https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/spring-integration-test/tree/main

The goal is that at startup there is a simulation of 2 emails that are sent, but the handling of the email sending fails. I would like to see that Spring Integration keeps trying to send the emails every 1 second and that the database contains entries for those emails. So if I stop the program and start it again, the retries keep happening.

When I run this now, in 90% of the time, I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into _spring_integration_CHANNEL_MESSAGE(
    MESSAGE_ID,
    GROUP_KEY,
    REGION,
    CREATED_DATE,
    MESSAGE_PRIORITY,
    MESSAGE_BYTES)
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
]; Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
```

One thing I have noticed is that if I change the poller from:

```
poller.fixedDelay(1000).transactional()
```

to

```
poller.fixedDelay(1000,1000).transactional()
```

Then the problem does not seem to happen anymore because the "emails" have probably already been inserted in the database by the time the poller starts. But that is probably just a fix that is not really a fix as this lock problem could appear at any time in a real application I guess?

Comment: You noted that changing the poller configuration seemed to alleviate the issue. While this might not be a definitive fix, it suggests that timing and transaction management are key factors. You might need to fine-tune the poller's fixed delay or even its transactional settings.

Comment: Seems to be an issue in Spring Integration 6.2.0: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8818

Comment: See more info in this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for your project is like this:

```
.handle(sendEmailMessageHandler, e ->
        e.poller(poller ->
                    poller.fixedDelay(1000)
                        .transactional(
                                        new TransactionInterceptorBuilder()
                                                .isolation(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
                                                .build())))
```

If you cannot set the `transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED` for your DB somehow.